# How to use keyword arguments when creating struct instances

Tags: racket

Suppose I have this struct:

```
(struct pos (x y))
```

I can create instances of this struct using:

```
(pos 1 2)
```

Suppose I want to use keyword arguments instead. For example:

```
(pos #:x 1 #:y 2)
```

This results in an error:

```
> (pos #:x 1 #:y 2)
; application: procedure does not accept keyword arguments
;   procedure: pos
; [,bt for context]
```

How can I use keyword arguments when creating instances of structs?

Comment: I always do this by just defining a constructor function by hand.  When I've done that I then spend some time trying to work out how to define some syntax which does this for me, but that is always too hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with native `struct`, so you either have to roll your own constructor as @tfb suggests, or use third-party libraries that provide this feature.

- https://docs.racket-lang.org/struct-plus-plus/
- https://docs.racket-lang.org/rebellion/Record_Types.html